# How to prevent Firefox reload when changing element position/size?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a div which contains a flash object. The flash has a button that maximizes that object to the full height/width of the browser window[a sort full screen option but limited to the browser]. When ever the position[top,left] is changed it refreshes the content. Because the flash object pushes data back and forth between the web app this causes problems. How can I make this change without triggering a reload? This seems to be an issue only in Firefox.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Answer (score 1):

it's an **8 year old** bug. excellent.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268